# how to change slack-bot name dynamically by using slack api in python

Tags: python, slack-api

i have one slack-app and this app I am using more than one sub-domain, when I am registering slack-app from the all sub-domain in One Slack team(SLACK-TEAM) then it should be change slack-bot name in duration of registering...

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Suppose there is a domain example.com and there are two subdomain in it abc.example.com and xyz.example.com

and we are registring both domain to the same slack team,
now when are querying slackbot we are getting more than one response i.e in this case we are getting 2 response.
and so on
 
when we have 3 subdomain added to same slack team we are getting 3 responses from salck bo

Comment: Please clarify your question. 1. What is your situation? 2. What do you want to achieve? 3. What is the problem?

Comment: e.g. what do you mean by "from the all sub-domain in One Slack team(SLACK-TEAM)"?